# How to add f1 metric to tensorflow multi class DNN Classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to add the f1 score to a canned DNNClassifier on tensorflow. There are 3 labels which i think is causing the problem when trying to add the f1_score metric using the tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics function.

I get the error Shapes (?, 3) and (?, 1) are incompatible. I am at a loss, will appreciate any help.

> File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\metrics_impl.py", line 116, in _remove_squeezable_dimensions
>       predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
>     File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 848, in assert_is_compatible_with
>       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
>   ValueError: Shapes (?, 3) and (?, 1) are incompatible

I have the following code:

```
   def my_f1(features, labels, predictions):
         return {'auc': tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(
                 labels, predictions['logits'], weights=features['weight'])}






    est = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                 n_classes=3,
                                 config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                                     save_checkpoints_steps=100,
                                     keep_checkpoint_max=5000,
                                 ),
                                 activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
                                 optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
                                     learning_rate=0.01,
                                     l1_regularization_strength=0.005
                                 ),
                                 weight_column='weight',
                                 dropout=0.5,
                                 hidden_units=[800, 450, 200, 100, 50],
                                 model_dir="D:/Stock Data/NeuralNetwork2"
                                 )
    est = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(est, my_f1)
```

Comment: you haven't added the my_f1 function in tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(est, metric_auc).

Comment: @heenabawa Thanks but that was a typo when copy pasting. I believe you cannot use the metrics for multiclass classification. It's only for binary it seems :/

Comment: could you print the shape of the labels? depending on the way it's been code, you could get a tensor like this [[0,0,1],[0,1,0]] or like this [3,2] which would explain the difference.